# How to easily check the number of whitespaces in a string?

Tags: javascript

Basically for every letter in a string I will be increasing an integer by 1.
The string length function would work perfectly, but it will include spaces as part of the length. I only want the number of characters in a string, not including spaces.

How can you check how many spaces a string has?
I could then subtract that value from the `string.length`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for counting the number of non-blank character in your string:

```
yourString.replace(/\s/g, "").length
```